# SQL Backups to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, regions

I have the following Amazon EC2 configuration

1. Prod Web & DB server (Virginia)
2. Web & DB server (Oregon)

I would like to store my SQL backups in S3 so that they are available to be restored to my standby server in case the Virginia region goes down for any period of time (which has been known to happen :)

Here are the following 2 regions I am considering for my S3 bucket

1. US Standard
2. Oregon

I attempted first to specify Oregon.  However, when I do that, I am unable (for some reason) to upload to that bucket from my Virginia instance.  However, I am worried that if I specify US Standard, that my S3 bucket will not be available in the event Virginia becomes unavailable.

Does anyone have any recommendations for overcoming the issues with either of these scenarios?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation for you is to use RDS (Relational Database Service), which is basically managed RDBMS service for MySQL (or MS-SQL or Oracle). It takes care for backup and restore for the DB.

With MySQL is has the option to have an automatic stand-by in a different availability zone in each region. When you use the option for "[Multi-AZ](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#42)", it will create the stand-by with its backup in a synchronize way. This way your fail over will be very close to real time.